No Ip with server apache
First of all, sorry for my English but I will try my best. I want to access my database outside my network, so I created a No-IP account, installed DUC, and configured Apache to run on XAMPP. I have an endpoint on PHP in Apache just for testing, a GET method that returns "Hello".
if (isset($_GET['nombre'])) {
    $nombre = $_GET['nombre'];
    $saludo = "¡Hola, $nombre!";    
    echo $saludo;
} else {
    // 
}

If I make a test on Postman using my endpoint with the no IP hostname, it works to return hello and the name, but if I try this with my app in Java and even try this on vb.net, it shows an error 404:
<html>
<head><title>Error 404: Not Found</title></head>
<body>
<h1>Error 404: Not Found</h1>
</body>
</html>

And if I try method to post, the error is 501 not implemented. I try many configurations on Apache to create a virtual host and .htaccess files. What do I need to include?

Show the code you use to call your endpoint.

Check your Apache log to see what requests you're receiving.

This is probably an Apache problem, not PHP. PHP doesn't care about the hostname unless you write code that checks things like $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']

all my System works perfect insede the network, so the code is fine but when i change the url from this: http://192.168.xx.xxx/mylogin/login.php to this http://myhostname.noip.net/mylogin/login.php gives the error 501. also theres something more, inside my network if i put my domain on the explorer it shows the controlpanel of the router, but if i do it for example on my cellphone outside the network i can see the page of xamp, thats the same reazon why PostMan also works. there no log on apache cause the requests never come
